# OpenGL ES glClearColor at 0.5 turns white

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I set glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), and when it is drawing, for a brief moment I can see everything is normal, but it very quickly fades out completely white. I also notice this effect is also happening to one of my textures that use the same numbers as it's background. What is the reason it is doing this, and what is needed to do to make it just render the colour #7f7f7f, which I hope will solve my texture problem, which appears to be suffering under the same effect.

Comment: Is this the only place you call glClearColor?

Comment: What is causing the fade-out? Something somewhere is causing a "fade-out" over time, what is the cause?

Comment: Would rendering to texture first, might cause this behaviour?

Comment: could also be caused by a blend function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was something to do with the blend function. Returning to `glBlendFunc(GL_COLOR_SRC, GL_ONE)`, or something on those lines, before glClearColor, made it behave the way it originally did  (I was playing around with the blend function). This could probably solve my texture problem, if I had the time. Still not sure, however, if rendering to a texture first contribute to this anyway.

**UPDATE:** It was to do with the blend func and it appears that rendering texture does actually change the results. Putting `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO)` before rendering to screen, it completely changed the way it looked.